# ERROR: cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to setup the [pgexercises](http://pgexercises.com/gettingstarted.html) data in my local machine.  When I run: `psql -U <username> -f clubdata.sql -d postgres -x` I get the error: `psql:clubdata.sql:6: ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE SCHEMA in a read-only transaction`.

Why did it create a read-only database on my local machine?  Can I change this?

Comment: Which username are you using? Which access rights has this user? Can create databases?

Comment: In my case, I had another `psql -f` process running in a `screen`. Launching another `psql -f` (even using a different `-h`) gave me the error you describe. In this case you have to wait for the first `psql` process to finish, or use a different host to run the second `psql` command.

Comment: I know that this isn't a general solution, but when I encountered this problem, I had accidentally connected to the read-only replica of my primary database. When I tried `set transaction read write;`, I got the error `cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Reached out to pgexercises.com and they were able to help me.

I ran these commands(separately):

```
psql -U <username> -d postgres
begin;
set transaction read write;
alter database exercises set default_transaction_read_only = off;
commit;
\q
```

Then I dropped the database from the terminal `dropdb exercises` and ran script again `psql -U <username> -f clubdata.sql -d postgres -x -q`

Comment: Actually this solution works! I did this in Heruko app but no credentials needs there. Just started from 'begin'

Answer (score 57):

Normally the most plausible reasons for this kind of error are :

- trying create statements on a read-only replica (the entire instance is read-only).
- `<username>` has `default_transaction_read_only` set to ON
- the database has `default_transaction_read_only` set to ON

The script mentioned has in its first lines:

```
CREATE DATABASE exercises;
\c exercises
CREATE SCHEMA cd;
```

**and you report that the error happens with `CREATE SCHEMA`** at line 6, not before.

That means that the `CREATE DATABASE` does work, when run by `<username>`.
And it wouldn't work if any of the reasons above was directly applicable.

One possibility that would technically explain this would be that `default_transaction_read_only` would be `ON` in the `postgresql.conf` file, and set to `OFF` for the database `postgres`, the one that the invocation of psql connects to, through an `ALTER DATABASE` statement that supersedes the configuration file.

That would be why `CREATE DATABASE` works, but then as soon as it connects to a different database with `\c`, the `default_transaction_read_only` setting of the session would flip to `ON`.

But of course that would be a pretty weird and unusual configuration.

Comment: Looked at my postgresql.conf file and `default_transaction_read_only
` is set to off.

Answer (score 37):

I was having getting `cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction`, `cannot execute DELETE TABLE in a read-only transaction` and others.

They all followed a `cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction`. It was like the connection had switched itself over to read-only in the middle of my batch processing.

**Turns out, I was running out of storage**!

Write access was disabled when the database could no longer write anything. I am using Postgres on Azure. I don't know if the same effect would happen if I was on a dedicated server.

Comment: This was my issue as well, but the solution isn't here so for anyone on DigitalOcean for example, use `SET default_transaction_read_only = OFF;`

Comment: Also on Azure Postgres, Flexible server. I had to restart the server to clear out the read only attribs on the entire database before I could do any cleanup to make some storage headroom.

Answer (score 11):

I had same issue for `Postgre` Update statement

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25006 ERROR: cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
```

Verified `Database` access by running below query and it will return either `true` or `false`

```
SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()
```

`true` -> Database has only Read Access

`false` -> Database has full Access

if returns true then check with DBA team for the full access and also try for `ping` in `command prompt` and ensure the connectivity.

```
ping <database hostname or dns>
```

Also verify if you have primary and standby node for the database

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Azure Database for PostgreSQL your server gets into read-only mode when the storage used is near total capacity.

The error you get is exactly:

`ERROR:  cannot execute XXXXXXXXX in a read-only transaction`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-compute-storage

Answer (score 6):

Dbeaver: In my case
[image]

This was on.

Comment: This was my case, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a master and replication nodes, and the master node became replication node, which I believe switched it into `hot_standby` mode. So I was trying to write data into a node that was meant only for reading, therefore the "read-only" problem.

You can query the node in question with `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()`, and if it returns `True` then it is "read-only", and I suppose you should switch to using whatever master node you have now.

I got this information from: https://serverfault.com/questions/630753/how-to-change-postgresql-database-from-read-only-to-writable.
So full credit and my thanks goes to Craig Ringer!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer the original question, but I received the same error and found this page, which ultimately led to a fix.

My issue was trying to run a function with temp tables being created and dropped. The function was created with `SECURITY DEFINER` privileges, and the user had access locally.

In a different environment, I received the `cannot execute DROP TABLE in a read-only transaction` error message. This environment was AWS Aurora, and by default, non-admin developers were given read-only privileges. Their server connections were thus set up to use the read-only node of Aurora (`-ro-` is in the connection url), which must put the connection in the read-only state. Running the same function with the same user against the write node worked.

Seems like a good use case for table variables like SQL Server has! Or, at least, AWS should modify their flow to allow temp tables to be created and dropped on read nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue with an RDS instance cluster, please check your endpoint and use the Writer instance endpoint. Then it should work now.

Comment: I had 3 running instances. One of then was write-enabled, and others were read-only. Worked by choosing the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred when I was restoring a production database locally, the database is still doing online recovery from the WAL records.

A little bit unexpected as I assumed pgbackgrest was creating instantly recoverable restores, perhaps not.

```
 91902 postgres  20   0 1445256  14804  13180 D   4.3  0.3   0:28.06 postgres: startup   recovering 000000010000001E000000A5
```

Answer (score 0):

If like me you are trying to **create DB on heroku** and are stuck as this message shows up on the dataclip tab

I did this,

```
Choose Resources from(Overview Resources Deploy Metrics Activity Access Settings)
```

```
Choose Settings out of (Overview, Durability, Settings, Dataclip)
```

```
Then in Administration->Database Credentials choose View Credentials...
```

then open terminal and fill that info here and enter

```
psql --host=***************.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=*********pubxl --password --dbname=*******lol
```

then it'll ask for password, copy-paste from there and you can run Postgres cmds.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly started facing this error on postgres installed on my windows machine, when I was running `alter` query from dbeaver, all I did was **deleted the connection** of postgres from dbeaver and **created a new connection**

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error.  My cause was not granting permission to the SEQUENCE

```
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE word_mash_word_cube_template_description_reference_seq TO ronshome_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be due to Intellij config:

```
Go to Database view> click on Data Source Properties (Shift + enter)> (Select your data source)> 
Options tab> Under Connection : uncheck Read-only
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Azure PostgreSQL failing over to standby during maintaince in Azure and never failing back to master when PostgreSQL was in HA mode. You can check this event in Service Health and also check which zone you current VM is running from. If it's 2 and not 1 them most likely that's the result of events described above.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when Azure Postgres reached 95% capaticty. I was not aware that they will switch all databases to read-only. Solution would be to either increase limit, clean your database or manually set back to write mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-limits#storage