# Dataclip Error ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-6

I want to insert data in Heroku but I can't do it because it's have error is "Dataclip Error

```
ERROR:  cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction"
```

[image: this picture]

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing this error?

Comment: it's like a pictute

Comment: I just run code insert in heroku

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31216995/4575350

Comment: Thats possible if you set the transaction flag explicitly to read write. Here is an example:

    begin;
    set transaction read write;
    
    your SQL query;
    
    COMMIT;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku's [Dataclips](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips) appear to be [designed for *viewing* data](https://blog.heroku.com/new-dataclips#what-is-a-dataclip), not modifying it:

> A Dataclip is a secret URL that holds the results of a SQL query on a particular Heroku Postgres database. Given the unique, private URL for a query, a user can call up the most recently stored results of that query. Our system will automatically re-run the Dataclip from time to time in order to keep results fresh. By sharing a Dataclip URL the same way you would share the underlying data, any recipient can view that data within, download it as a CSV, or even embed it live into a tool like Google Sheets.

It is very likely that you can't modify data using this tool.

If you're just trying to insert some data, use a regular database client.